# How do I configure Android x86 for dual monitor (i.e. cloning)?

Tags: android, x86, multiple-monitors

I have installed Android x86 4.4-r2 on an Intel x86 platform with two display connectors: HDMI and DVI. The HDMI connector shall be wired to a 7 inches touchscreen and the DVI to a large monitor, which shall be powered on-demand (e.g. for watching videos). [**EDIT**: The ideal configuration would be an extended desktop view but so far I'm only considering display cloning.]

So far the second display is blank (no image). How can I configure Android x86 for dual monitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sought Android x86 mailing list and it turns out [it's not possible at the moment](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/android-x86/dual%2420monitor/android-x86/-niTz7H0f_A/PDLjPr4Px-oJ).

Answer (score 1):

Cloning works in recent builds from http://www.android-x86.org/download, specifically with android-x86_64-7.1-r2.iso with an external monitor connected via HDMI cable. No extra setup was necessary. But there doesn't seem to be way to set the resolution of the external monitor.